# Rebuild a dynamic library upon parameter addition to function

Tags: c++, dll

Got a question regarding dynamic libraries in C++, I have a dll which a number of other dlls are linking to and I want to add a parameter to one of the exported functions in that dll.
Do I need to rebuild all of the dlls linking to it with the new lib or just the ones that actually call that specific function?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild will be required for the ones which actually call that specific function which got a new parameter.

`lib` of a `DLL` helps in resolving the names used in `executable/other dll` which is linked to `DLL`. So for `executables/dlls` which do not call the function (inside of dll) whose signature has been changed, are not required to be rebuild.

But as a good practice "whenever possible", from consistency point of view, every one using a newer version of of `dll` should be rebuild.